# Getting text from ModelDropdown in react native app development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I would like to know how we can retrieve text from ModelDropdown upon selecting an option:

```
import ModalDropdown from 'react-native-modal-dropdown';
...

export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  category: '',    
}
}

updateCategory(newCategory) {
this.setState({
  category: newCategory
})
}

....

<ModalDropdown 
        style={{padding: 20}}
        options={['Electronics', 'Furniture']}
        textStyle={{fontSize: 20, color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold',}}
        dropdownTextStyle={{fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: '#FFF', color: 'black'}}
        defaultValue = 'Select Category'
        onSelect={(newCategory) => this.updateCategory(newCategory)}
/>
```

I m getting index value, like "0" for Electronics and "1" for Furniture.
I would like to get the text corresponding to that index.

Or is there any alternative to ModelDropdown which may help me in accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are getting corresponding index so you can easily take value from options array, just set it in state or some global variable.
you can do something like this.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        options:['Electronics', 'Furniture'],    
    }
}
```

and then in updateCategory take value like this

```
updateCategory(newCategory) {
    this.setState({
      textValue: this.state.options[newCategory]
    })
}
```